Betti numbers: $b_k=b_{n−k}$, and $b_{n/2}$ is even if $n$ is even. Make an n-dimensional closed, oriented manifold with these Betti numbers (redo).
I attempted this problem yesterday, but it was made clear to me that I didn't understand what the prompt wanted. I have re-done this problem with a construction that I feel is accurate.
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I consulted Hatcher's book for this problem, but I have seen no proof for this problem anywhere; all work is my own. As a consequence my proofs may be eccentric and nonoptimal, even when they are correct.


Let $ b_0, b_1, \dots , b_n $ be a sequence of positive integers satisfying $ b_k = b_{n−k} $ for all $ k $, and $ b_{n/2} $ is even if $ n $ is even. Construct an $ n $-dimensional closed, oriented manifold with these Betti numbers.

Answer: My strategy involved translating this topological problem into an algebraic one (through induced vector spaces). After solving within the vector space, I then reversed the functor and gave the wanted topological construction.
We'll view our sequence of Betti numbers as a vector, with addition of vectors induced by the disjoint union of the underlying topological spaces. As it turns out, solving this problem reduces to finding a collection of topological spaces that induce a basis on this vector space.
We'll use the same symbol ($+$) for the disjoint union of spaces and the induced addition of vectors. We'll use the same symbol (#) for the connected sum of spaces and the induced connected sum of vectors (which we'll define shortly). Multiplication of a topological space by an integer $\alpha$ represents performing the disjoint union of a space by itself $\alpha$ times. Multiplication of a vector by a scalar integer $\alpha$ corresponds to ordinary scalar multiplication.
From context, it will be obvious which of the two meanings each operation has.
Represent our Betti numbers $x_i$ for a space $X$ as a "Betti vector" over $\mathbb{N}$:
$$
B(X) = (x_0 , \dots , x_n) = \sum_i x_i  \mathbf{e}_i
$$
Where addition and scalar multiplication are defined straightforwardly. The connected sum of two Betti vectors $B(X)$ and $B(Y)$ is defined on the subspace of vectors where all positive values are in the range $0 \le k \le n$ and where $x_0 = y_0 = x_n = y_n = 1$:
$$
B(X) \text{#} B(Y) = B(X) + B(Y) - (\mathbf{e}_0 + \mathbf{e}_n)
$$
We know that when we take the product of two underlying topological spaces, the Betti numbers transform according to the Künneth formula. For our torsion-free case, we can define the "Künneth product" $\mathsf{K}$ of two vectors as the Betti number result of taking the product of the two underlying topological spaces:
$$ 
(B(X) \text{  } \mathsf{K} \text{  } B(Y))_k 
$$
$$ = \sum_{i + j = k} x_i y_j \mathbf{e}_k $$
Then a correct basis (orthogonal modulo $\mathbf e_0$ and $\mathbf e_n$) can be written as for an $n$-dimensional Betti vector $B(X)$ as: $$\{B(S^n)\} \cup \{ B(S^n) \text{  } \mathsf{K} \text{  } B(S^{n-j}) \}_i  $$
for $0 \le j \le n/2$ if $n$ is even, and $0 \le j \le (n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd.
As a consequence, we can write our vector $B(X)$ as:
$$
B(X) = \text{#}_{i,j} \left(B(S^n) \text{  } \mathsf{K} \text{  } B(S^{n-j})\right) + \alpha B(S^n)
$$
where non-negative $\text{#}_{i,j}$ means that we take a connected sum of some $i(j)$ copies of each $j$th basis element (and thus we can span the entire vector space). We can vacuously interpret $i(j) =0$ as not connected summing the basis vector.
Since the induced operations on vectors directly line up with the induced operations on topological spaces, the underlying space $X$ for any of our Betti number sequences can be constructed as:
$$
X = \text{#}_{i,j} \left(S^n \times S^{n-j}\right) + \alpha S^n
$$

(a) Is this underlying space $X$ correct?
As a bonus, if there are faster and better methods to deduce this construction (involving theorems that have eluded me), then I'd love to see it.
Thanks in advance.

Your proof is more or less correct, but there are some inessential inaccuracies. You speak of a "vector space" and a "basis", but there is no such things as a vector space of Betti vectors (they don't have inverses, for example). The essential part of the argument is a) noting how disjoint union and connected sum interact with the Betti numbers of closed, oriented manifolds and b) using this to show that all "Betti vectors" can be obtained by taking the disjoint union of some copies of $S^n$ and the connected sum of some $S^i\times S^{n-i}$. You should, however, pay more heed to how many copies exactly of what product of spheres you need to take the connected sum of, because your proof as given does not highlight why $b_{n/2}$ being even (in case $n$ is even) is an essential hypothesis! (By the way, the assumptions can be relaxed to allow $b_1,\dotsc,b_{n-1}$ to be non-negative rather than strictly positive, without changing the argument.) For more information on what happens if you drop the assumption that $b_{n/2}$ is even (in case $n$ is even) as well as another presentation of this argument, I recommend the talk What are the Betti numbers of a manifold? by Don Zagier.

Any formal term for what to call the "vector space"? It might be something like a "monoid for a graded structure", but I wouldn't know if there's a proper name for this thing. I verified on paper that the spheres (represented as "Betti Vectors") under the "Kunneth Product form a basis and guarantee that in even dimensions $b_{n/2}$ is even, but I felt that if I included that section my derivation might get too long winded for people to handle. Also, thanks for the talk recommendation! I'll check it out.

The Betti vectors under disjoint union also do not have an identity element, so they merely are a semigroup. If you permit the entries to all be non-negative rather than strictly positive (and hence permit the empty manifold), the Betti vectors under disjoint union are a commutative monoid. The "connected" Betti vectors (i.e. $b_0=b_n=1$) are a commutative monoid under connected sum. Either of these have a "basis" (a free generating set), but you need to specify which you are talking about. In any case, these algebraic statements are more overcomplicating than helpful to the question IMO.
